# any good ways to do mediamuxer on android?

Tags: android, video, encode, hardware-acceleration, mediamuxer

I am trying to build a video system on android. I am using the [sample](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forum/qdevnet-forums/multimedia-optimization-qdsp/12520) provided by Qualcomm, which allows me to use openmax and do hardware-acceleration on Qualcomm customer device.

Anyway, this sample only generates .h264 file. So I am looking forword a good way to do the muxer work. I've used [MediaMuxer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer.html) before, but it supports system later than android4.3, so this doesn't work on this sample. (Qualcomm sample only support android4.2 and before)

Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ffmpeg. build ffmpeg for android, create jni wrapper and easily expose muxing functionality to java level